# On Mountain Lion, how do I use Xdebug under Sublime Text 2 for use with a remote server?

Tags: php, xdebug

I'm looking to access a remote machine (SSH, SFTP, whatever) and debug some PHP on it, and I'm looking to use Xdebug. From what I see, [Xdebug is installed by default in Mountain Lion](http://www.lullabot.com/blog/articles/configuring-xdebug-osx-mountain-lion), so I just enabled it, but I'm unsure where to go from now that I have it enabled.

How do I tell I have it installed? How do I use it in conjunction with Sublime Text 2 (assuming using the SublimeXdebug plugin) to debug remote PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using Sublime Text 2 to debug PHP is a bit tricky. It would be probably much easier for you to use some IDE like PHPStorm or NetBeans.

Anyway, this is what I would do:

1. Check my `phpinfo()` that xdebug is really enabled
2. On my development environment set [`xdebug.remote_connect_back`](http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_connect_back) = 1. This makes Xdebug to connect back to the client that made the request. Use it only on your development environment!
3. Run your debugger in Sublime Text 2. It should be waiting for Xdebug to connect.
4. Open my website in a browser with `XDEBUG_SESSION_START` parameter URL http://mywebsite.localhost/?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=1.
5. Xdebug should connect to your Sublime Text 2 debugger client.